# Project from GCS_WGS_1984 to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, web-mercator

What is the default transformation method to project data from from GCS_WGS_1984(WIKI 4326) to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere(WIKI 3857)?

ArcMap 10.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none because both coordinate reference systems (CRS) are based on WGS 1984. No geographic/datum transformation is needed.

If you happen to use the "old" Web Mercator version, "WGS_1984_Web_Mercator" aka EPSG::3785 or Esri::102113, the geographic CRS is sphere-based and you should use WGS_1984_Major_Auxiliary_Sphere_To_WGS_1984.

Comment: I never worry about those CRS issues as I know Melita is around on GIS.SE... :D great to have you here.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Thank you, thank you. It's great to be here!